# Shared Preferences store always the last parameter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I storing preferences of my app in shared prefences.

The problem is that when I try to get the preferences stored always get the same value, in specific, the last value that I store when create the "session"

this is the code when click in the button to store the preferences

```
//BUTTON TO STORE PREFERENCES IF THE CONNECTION TO FTP IS SUCCEFULLY
        final TextView guardarconexionconftp= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label_guardar_conexionconftp);
        guardarconexionconftp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                FTPHandler ftp = new FTPHandler(ConfigActivity.this);
                TextView dirftp= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dirftp);
                TextView userftp= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userftp);
                TextView passftp= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.passftp);
                TextView logoutconexionconftp= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label_guardar_conexionconftp);
                String[] ftpurl = dirftp.getText().toString().split(":"); String ftpuser = userftp.getText().toString(); String ftppass = passftp.getText().toString(); 
                if(ftpurl.length < 2) System.out.println("Direccion");
                else if(ftpuser.length() == 0) System.out.println("User");
                else if(ftppass.length() == 0) System.out.println("Pass");
                else{
                if(ftp.ftpConnect(ftpurl[0], ftpuser, ftppass, Integer.parseInt(ftpurl[1]))){
                    //STORE PREFERENCES
                    SessionManager session2;
                    session2 = new SessionManager(ConfigActivity.this);
                    System.out.println(ftpurl[0].toString() + " " + ftpuser.toString() + " " + ftppass.toString() + " " + ftpurl[1].toString());
                    session2.createFTPLoginSession(ftpurl[0].toString(), ftpuser.toString(),ftppass.toString(),ftpurl[1].toString());
                    guardarconexionconftp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    logoutconexionconftp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.camposconexion).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editftp.setText("Conectado con a FTP");
                    findViewById(R.id.camposftp).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    System.out.println("Disconnect " + ftp.ftpDisconnect());
                    System.out.println("print stored: " + session2.getFTPUrl() + " " + session2.getFTPUser() + " " + session2.getFTPpass() + " " + session2.getFTPPort());
                    }
                    else Toast.makeText(ConfigActivity.this, "No ha sido posible conectarse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
            });
```

and this is the class to store and read sharedpreferences

```
package com.asde.telemedicina;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "TelemedicinaPref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "false";

    private static final String IS_LOGINFTP = "false";

    private static final String KEY_NOMBRE = "name";

    private static final String KEY_REGISTRO = "regcode";

    private static final String KEY_COLEGIADO = "colecode";

    private static final String KEY_IDIOMA = "ES";

    private static final String KEY_TIDIOMA = "notset";

    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "pass";

    private static final String KEY_PIRACY = "mykey";

    private static final String KEY_URLFTP = "";

    private static final String KEY_USERFTP = "";

    private static final String KEY_PASSFTP = "";

    private static final String KEY_PORTFTP = "";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_UPDATE = "notasked";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }



    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String n, String r, String col,String l){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing regcode in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NOMBRE, n);

        // Storing regcode in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_REGISTRO, r);

        // Storing regcode in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_COLEGIADO, col);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_IDIOMA, l);

        // Set Piracy system
        editor.putString(KEY_PIRACY, getMW());

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }   

    public void createFTPLoginSession(String url, String user, String password,String port){

        System.out.println(url + " " + user + " " + password + " " + port);

        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGINFTP, true);

        // Storing url ftp in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_URLFTP, url);

        // Storing userftp in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_USERFTP, user);

        // Storing ftp pass in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSFTP, password);

        // Storing ftp port in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_PORTFTP, port);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();

    }

    public String getFTPUrl(){

        return  pref.getString(KEY_URLFTP, null);
    }  

    public String getFTPUser(){
        return  pref.getString(KEY_USERFTP, null);
    }  

    public String getFTPpass(){
        return  pref.getString(KEY_PASSFTP, null);
    }  

    public String getFTPPort(){
        return  pref.getString(KEY_PORTFTP, null);
    }  

    public String getPiracy(){
        return  pref.getString(KEY_PIRACY, null);
    }   

    public String getMW(){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) _context.getSystemService(_context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress(); 
        return macAddress;
    } 

    public String getLanguage(){
        return  pref.getString(KEY_IDIOMA, null);
    }    

    public void setTlanguage(String l)
    {
        editor.putString(KEY_TIDIOMA, l);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getTlanguage()
    {
        return pref.getString(KEY_TIDIOMA, "null");
    }
    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    public void checkFTPLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedInFTP()){

//          // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
//          Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
//          // Closing all the Activities
//          i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//
//          // Add new Flag to start new Activity
//          i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//
//          // Staring Login Activity
//          _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_REGISTRO, pref.getString(KEY_REGISTRO, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_NOMBRE, pref.getString(KEY_NOMBRE, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */


    public void logoutFTPUser(){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
                editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGINFTP, false);

                // Storing url ftp in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_URLFTP, "");

                // Storing userftp in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_USERFTP, "");

                // Storing ftp pass in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_PASSFTP, "");

                // Storing ftp port in pref
                editor.putInt(KEY_PORTFTP, 0);

                // commit changes
                editor.commit();

}

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }

    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedInFTP(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGINFTP, false);
    }
}
```

Always store in all KEYS the last prefence that try to store, ex: if the last parameter is the port in  KEY_PORTFTP, when try to print all of the other keys print the KEY_PORTFTP value.

Must be silly but I am not able to see
Someone can i help me?

Comment: You have four `KEY_*`s that are empty Strings. `KEY_URLFTP`, `KEY_USERFTP`, `KEY_PASSFTP`, and `KEY_PORTFTP`.

Comment: Also, `IS_LOGIN` and `IS_LOGINFTP` are the same, i.e. `"false"`. If these are all keys in the same SharedPreferences file, they all need to be different.

Comment: The same? But the variables `KEY*` and `is_` have different names and when create a session with `createFTPLoginsession` I initialize his values and save to pref. Is not correct?

Comment: Not quite. The _values_ of `KEY_*` and `IS_*` are what matters.  Say `KEY_PORTFTP = "portftp"`.  When you call `pref.getString(KEY_PORTFTP, null)` it's looking for the preference that's associated with `"portftp"`, not the variable name `KEY_PORTFTP`.

Comment: Then, if I try to get KEY_IDIOMA that is initiated to "ES" how can it works. Not exist relation o.0

Comment: If `pref.getString(KEY_IDIOMA, null)` returns `"ES"` then `l` must have equaled `"ES"` when you called `editor.putString(KEY_IDIOMA, l)`.

Comment: Then,If I understand correctly, when use pref.getString(KEY_USERFTP, null) internally access to the value via default value of the variable. Is your key to get the value of the variable. No?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. But think of it like this: you don't _have_ to use the `KEY_*` variables; they're just for convenience. You could get rid of them all, and do: `pref.putString("idioma", l)`, `l = pref.getString("idioma", null)`, `pref.putString("userftp", user)`, `user = pref.getString("userftp", null)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void logoutFTPUser(){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
                editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGINFTP, false);

                // Storing url ftp in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_URLFTP, "");

                // Storing userftp in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_USERFTP, "");

                // Storing ftp pass in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_PASSFTP, "");

                // Storing ftp port in pref
                editor.putInt(KEY_PORTFTP, 0);

                // commit changes
                editor.commit();

}


Instead of this You can use like follow





    public void logoutFTPUser(){
            // Storing login value as TRUE
                editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGINFTP, false);

                editor.commit();

                // Storing url ftp in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_URLFTP, "");

                editor.commit();

                // Storing userftp in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_USERFTP, "");

                editor.commit();

                // Storing ftp pass in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_PASSFTP, "");

                editor.commit();

                // Storing ftp port in pref
                editor.putInt(KEY_PORTFTP, 0);

                // commit changes
                editor.commit();

}




and Now You can get All The Items. Once You Assign the Value for One Key. You Should Commit the Editor. Then,Only you can get that value
```